# What does implementation inheritance mean in the javadoc of java.sql.Timestamp?

Tags: java, sql, inheritance, jdbc, timestamp

From the [JavaDoc of java.sql.Timestamp class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)(emphasis mine)

Due to the differences between the Timestamp class and the java.util.Date class mentioned above, it is recommended that code not view Timestamp values generically as an instance of java.util.Date. **The inheritance relationship between Timestamp and java.util.Date really denotes implementation inheritance, and not type inheritance**.

What does it mean to say *implementation inheritance* and not *type inheritance*? Is it a case of HAS-A vs IS-A?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, the documentation states that the fact that `java.sql.Timestamp` extends `java.util.Date` is an implementation detail, and you should not use `Timestamp` instances where you expect to get `Date`'s  functionality. Presumably, if java had the option (like C++ does), `Timestamp` would privately inherit from `Date`.

Answer (score 3):

What they mean is that they designed Timestamp as a subclass of Date not to have polymorphism and because a Timestamp is a Date, but because they wanted to easily reuse code from the Date class.